# Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, libreoffice, gnucash

My friend is going to help me upgrade my operating system tomorrow, from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 (or perhaps Lubuntu, I'm not quite sure). I'm going to back up all my files tonight and put them on another machine, since I'm not sure if we're going to lose all my data or not.

My question is to do with the data that I have, and whether or not I should expect problems once the new operating system is up and running, since all the programs will be newer versions. As far as I can make out the only programs I use are:

- LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 (I think I'll move to 7.5.6)
- Foxit Reader 2.4.1.0609 (I think I'll move to 2023.2.0.21408)
- GNUcash 2.5.12 (I think I'll move to 5.4)

I run a small carpentry business, and as you can probably see I want to keep things simple, and have a reliable outcome, hence why I'm opting for stable releases of everything. I'm also not very good at all of this, which is why my friend is helping me!

If I install the new, stable programs (once the OS is sorted), and then simply move all my backed up data back on to my computer can I expect them to work straight away? Or are there any preventative measures that I should do ahead of time?

Finally, I've been using Firefox as my browser for many years, and I've been happy with it. Should I consider using another browser, perhaps Chrome? (I use Gmail, and I'm considering using GoogleDocs so that I can access data while I'm off on-site, and I was wondering if Chrome might be a smoother, faster experience). I'm not too concerned about privacy, since I don't have the technical nous to implement it anyway.

EDIT:
Thank you for all the input, we've ended up installing Lubuntu 22.04 and everything seems to work so far. The only two niggles I've run into is that I can't get reports to work in GNUCash 4.8 (which is very serious), and the screen gets slightly glitchy when scrolling in Firefox (not serious, just annoying). If anyone has thoughts on how I can resolve the GNUCash problem I'd love to hear it, I wasn't sure if I should post it as a new question or not.

Comment: Does the current computer have an HDD or an SSD? It might be a good opportunity to upgrade if it has an HDD.

Answer (score 1):

1. Since this PC has valued business data, **make a full disk image and verify that it works** using [dd](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-clone-restore-linux-disk-image-dd/) or other tool. You can even use a Windows application from USB, such as [Macrium Reflect Rescue Environment](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61). A disk image allows you to revert to 16.04 with all data *and* operating system intact if a disaster occurs in the update, or even should the HDD die.
2. Decide if 22.04 is best, or 20.04 LTS (long term service) better suits your use. While 22.04 is more recent, its EOL (end of life) is [April 2027](https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu), whereas 20.04 LTS will be updated through April 2030 ([using Pro extended security support](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/enable-ubuntu-pro/), free for up to 5 machines).
3. Having upgraded older PC's, I find a two-step process more likely to succeed, though a bit more time-consuming. There *is* a path to upgrade from [16.04 to 18.04](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-to-ubuntu-18-04) (and see [this, too](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-16.04-to-18.04/)), and thence [to 20.04 LTS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/) (or even to 22.04).
4. Since you depend on this PC and have kept it for a long time, consider subscribing to [Ubuntu Pro](https://ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-pro). Perhaps your usage qualifies under [personal terms of service](https://ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-pro/personal), in which case it's free.
5. As for software, there is no reason at all to change browser - Firefox works just as well on newer versions of Ubuntu, though I prefer getting the [updates from Mozilla](https://itsfoss.com/firefox-esr-ubuntu/), rather than as a SNAP (which I've uninstalled on 20.04).

   [GNUCash](https://www.gnucash.org/) should be fine, as well. [Version 5.4](https://www.gnucash.org/news.phtml) was just released.

   [Foxit PDF editor](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-foxit-pdf-reader-on-ubuntu/) should work, but check on licensing. You might also consider one of the many other tools, such as free [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/), native to Linux, and Windows applications, such as versatile, fremium, [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) and *very* fast, free, [Sumatra PDF Reader](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader), which work *quite* well under wine.

   Finally, for email, I much prefer a singlemail reader such as [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/), rather than suffering through the varying interfaces in GMail, Hotmail, Yahoo Mail, etc. Thunderbird comes installed in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and can also be [installed directly through PPA](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-thunderbird-on-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, wine 8.0 (I keep it updated, since Ubuntu does *not*), Sumatra is flawless and faster than native Okular, which is*slow* to start. At least that is true for the 5 very different PC's I maintain. See https://www.winehq.org/search?q=sumatra for titlebar issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

There's no upgrade path from Ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04. Ubuntu 16.04 reached EoL (End of Life) status in April 2019!!

The way to go is indeed backing up your personal files and installing from scratch a supported release. Ubuntu 22.04 or any one of its derivatives (flavors) is a solid choice because it's a Long Time Support (LTS) release that can be easily upgraded to the next LTS, 24.04 (to be released in April 2024).

All your personal files should work with the new versions.

The web browser is personal choice. Google Chrome may provide a better or smoother integration of the Gioogle online services mentioned in the question but Firefox will work as well.